# Proof Verification: Putnam 1995 A4

Tags: proof-verification, contest-math

PROBLEM:

Suppose we have a necklace of $n$ beads. Each bead is labelled with an integer and the sum of all these labels is $n-1$. Prove that we can cut the necklace to form a string whose consecutive labels $x_1, x_2,\cdots , x_n$ satisfy

$\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i\le k-1\quad\forall\;\;1\le k\le n $

SOLUTION:

We use induction. The proposition is obviously true for $n=2$. Given that it is true for $n=k$ we prove it for a string $n = k+1$.

Define $S_i = \sum_{1}^{i} x_c$. As $S_n > 0$, there must be at least one nonnegative bead $x_{p+1}$. Decrease this bead by 1 and combine $x_{p}$ and $x_{p+1}$ into one bead, $B$. We now have a string of length $n = k$ whose sum is $k-1$; by the inductive hypothesis, we can cut it, say at $x_0$, such that the condition is met.

Now we separate the combined bead into $x_p$ and $x_{p+1}$ and raise the latter by 1, restoring the original string. The beads from $0 \cdots (p-1)$ meet the inequality since they have been unchanged. As $x_{p+1}$ is nonegative, $x_p \le B$ and so $S_p \le p-1$. Thus, $x_p$ meets the condition. For beads $(p+1) \cdots n$, $S$ has increased by 1 since $x_{p-1}$ was raised. However, since the combined bead was split, the right-hand-side of the inequality has increased by 1 as well.

Therefore, the string meets the condition, and the induction is complete.

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect? The proof seems to be valid.

Comment: @MayankPandey that is the kind of answer I am looking for. My proof is not among the ones in the solutions manual so I want confirmation that it is correct.

Comment: Looks ok. But one typo: $0\dots p$ should be $0\dots p-1$. Incidentally, I don't think it was in Putnam 1996. Are you sure you have the year correct?

Comment: @almagest It was 1995.

Answer (score 0):

Find biggest bead call it xp
After removing it we have n-1 beads, the consecutive substring  chosen starts with xp+1 ( the bead next to the one we cut ) this substring ends at xp-1 and must be less then n-2 since xp was at least positive 1. Next take the second largest bead where ever it is and cut again call it xp2. Reform the necklace .the same happens as now the substring starting with xp2+1 up xp2-1 has now 2 beads removed sums to =< n-3 since again these two beads are less then or equal to 1 .
We continue this was until we are left with negative beads to which there must be at least one . there fore the sum of n-1_ is less then n-2_as,n-2_less then n-3 and so on leading to sum xpi-1 from i=1 to k is =< k-1 for all (¥) k up to n

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).